# How to store and use data from BackBlaze B2 using Cloudflare in Flutter app where user data is already being managed in cloud Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, cloudflare, backblaze

**Description of my app:**
It's a social media type flutter app. Where users can post content and see each other's posts in home page.

In my app auth and user data (name, username, email, password, interests and other credentials) is being managed in Firebase firestore as you can see in the image.

[image: Firestore User data screenshot]

I want to use [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) to store the content (image/video) posted by the user and Cloudflare as a CDN.

My question is how do I interconnect all of this? I haven't built the functionality to post yet but user object is already created. I want to inter-connect Firestore, Backblaze B2 and Cloudflare CDN.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://blog.polyhaven.com/how-we-handle-80tb-and-5m-page-views-a-month-for-under-400/) explains a very similar use case leveraging Backblaze B2, Firestore and Cloudflare.

You will set up Backblaze as your origin store, with Cloudflare configured as the CDN, [as described here](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/217666928-Using-Backblaze-B2-with-the-Cloudflare-CDN). You'll store the Backblaze B2 image/video URLs - e.g. `https://f000.backblaze.com/file/images/img1234.png` - in Firestore.